# Adding a Column in R (character) based off of what is contained in another column (character) within the same data

Tags: r, conditional-statements, character

I am trying to add a column to my data based off of what is contained in a different column within the same data.
So just for an example of what i'm looking for:

Column A:
"Apple Bees in the right area"
"We love Apple Bees here"
"Waffle House: the place to go!  5 stars"
"Nothing better than Waffle House!"

*Note: Column A has value chr*

I want Column F to show:
"Apple Bees"
"Apple Bees"
"Waffle House"
"Waffle House"

I tried mutate, contains, select, %in%, and I kept getting a bunch of errors.  I assume I am supposed to use one or more of these within the dplyr package, but I am not getting the results I want.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

restaurants <- c("Apple Bees", 
                 "Waffle House") %>% 
  paste(collapse = "|")

my_df <- data.frame(
matrix(
  c(
    "Apple Bees in the right area",
    "We love Apple Bees here",
    "Waffle House: the place to go! 5 stars",
    "Nothing better than Waffle House!"
  ),
  nrow = 4,
  ncol = 1,
  byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(NULL,
                  c("phrase"))
),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

my_df_new <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(
    restaurant_in_phrase = str_extract(phrase, restaurants)
  )
```

If you're doing a lot of work with strings and phrases, I'd highly recommend familiarizing yourself with Regular Expressions or regex.